# how to disable user interaction for a button

Tags: iphone, button, user-interaction

i have a play button in my view,if i press play its gets updated the stream and started playing..
until i get play song i dont want to take any user interactions on play button..
can any ony help me on this.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the "Enabled" property to "NO" or if you want animation, fade the alpha out.